# Develop the the following Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am attempting to solve the following relation of recurrence:

> Knowing that $S_n$ is the number of binary strings of length $n$ that
>   does not contain the pattern $111$. Develop the relation of recurrence
>   for $S_1, S_2, ..., S_n$ and the initial conditions that defines the
>   succession of $S$.

I know that if $n$ is the length of the string and every character could only have two possible values then the number of combinations is $2^n$.

But these types of worded questions are not my strong points. Where do I begin and how do I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For n > 2, the binary sting with length n either ends with "0", "01" or "011". Hence the recurrence for $S_n$ is:

$$S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + S_{n-3}$$

With base cases
$S_0 = 1, S_1 = 2, S_2 = 4$.

Here I tried to divide the answer into several cases, each of which is of smaller length. And that was done by considering the position of the last zero in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, my previous answer answered the wrong question (and was wrong anyway! lol). I shouldnt do math 15 seconds after waking up. Anyway

Since we are developing a recurrence relation, we want to look at how $S_n$ changes compared to a previous $S_n$. Here it's pretty straight forward. If we increase $n$ by one we have twice as many possible strings. We'll still have any string from $S_{n-1}$ that contained a $111$, so we don't need to figure out those again, we just need to figure out what new strings contain a $111$ that didn't before.

Assuming we are adding the bit to the front (it doesnt change the answer if we add it to the back). If that bit is a $0$ obviously we can't be adding any $111$ sequence that we didn't already count. If we add a $1$, now any sequence before that started out $110...$ that didn't already contain a $111$ will now be $1110...$ and now need to be counted. So how many strings of $S_{n-1}$ started $110...$ and don't contain a $111$ arleady?

It's just the number of strings of length $(n-1)-3$ that don't contain a $111$ (since we were looking at strings of length $n-1$ and now we are chopping of the three bits that start $110$). Since any string of length $n-4$ that doesn't contain a $111$ we could now just stick a $110$ in front of and have a string of length $n-1$ that doesn't contains a $111$ which is what we are looking for.

So if we increase $n$ we have twice the total number of strings, and we have to remove from the count the number that was $S_{n-4}$. Thus $S_n = 2S_{n-1} - S_{n-4}$

hopefully thats right this time, heh.